# org.apache.solr.analysis.BufferedTokenStream class moved or dropped in solr 4.x?

Tags: java, solr, lexical-analysis, solr4

I am upgrading from solr 3.6.2 to solr 4.1.0. I encountered this problem when I used the`BufferedTokenStream` class. Is this class dropped, moved or renamed in solr 4.1.0?

The error I came across is:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/analysis/BufferedTokenStream

Answer (score 2):

`org.apache.solr.analysis.BufferedTokenStream` is deprecated in solr 3.6.2.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_2/deprecated-list.html#class

`Deprecated` usually means:

- it is not recommended to use this class
- this class may be removed in future

I would recommend to change the usage of `org.apache.solr.analysis.BufferedTokenStream` according Apache's recommendations:

> This class does not support custom attributes. Extend TokenFilter instead, using AttributeSource.captureState() and AttributeSource.restoreState(State) which support all attributes.